# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before... Error in C++/Objective-C iPhone project

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

So I'm going through the first tutorial in O'Reilly's iPhone 3D Programming book. At this point in the tutorial, it pulls all the OpenGL ES stuff into a seperate c++ interface. I have followed the book to the letter, as far as I can tell, yet I can't seem to figure out this compiler error. I'm fairly new to C++ (mostly C# in the past), so I'm sure it's something stupid.

Below is the current state of all the relevant files.

I have a c++ header file called **IRenderingEngine.hpp** with the following contents:

```
enum DeviceOrientation {
    Unknown,
    Portrait,
    PortraitUpsideDown,
    LandscapeLeft,
    LandscapeRight,
    FaceUp,
    FaceDown,
};

struct IRenderingEngine* CreateRenderer1();

struct IRenderingEngine {
    virtual void Initialize(int width, int height) = 0; //Compiler error "expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'virtual'
    virtual void Render() const = 0;
    virtual void UpdateAnimation(float timeStep) = 0;
    virtual void OnRotate(DeviceOrientation newOrientation) = 0;
    virtual ~IRenderingEngine() {}
};
```

I have an objective-c/c++ header file called **GLView.h** that looks like this:

```
#import "IRenderingEngine.hpp"
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface GLView : UIView {
    EAGLContext* m_context;
    IRenderingEngine* m_renderingEngine; //Compiler error: Expected specifier-qualifier-list before "IRenderingEngine"
    float m_timeStamp;
}

- (void) drawView: (CADisplayLink*) displayLink;
- (void) didRotate: (NSNotification*) notification;

@end
```

And finally, a **GLView.mm** file with a barebones implementation:

```
#import "GLView.h"


@implementation GLView

+ (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return self;
}

- (void) drawView:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{

}

-(void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{

}

@end
```

Comment: Besides `GLView.mm`, do you have any other plain `.m` files where you include one of these headers?

Comment: Only "Other Sources"/main.m and the AppDelegate.h and .m files, which I haven't touched since the beginning of the project.

Comment: Well, if `GLView.h` gets included in either of these, you'll get the error you mentioned. See my answer on how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message e.g. occurs if one of your two headers gets included in a plain Objective-C source file, which doesn't know anything about handling C++ code.

To allow `GLView` to be used from plain Objective-C sources, use only a forward declaration for the rendering engine and don't include the C++ header in `GLView.h`:

```
// GLView.h:
struct IRenderingEngine;
@interface GLView : UIView {
    struct IRenderingEngine* m_renderingEngine;
// ...
@end

// GLView.mm:
#import "IRenderingEngine.hpp"
// ... etc.
```

Alternatively you can use opaque pointers for wrapping C++ instances to keep the Objective-C interface more stable, see e.g. Rob Napiers [post](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-take-2-1-486) on the subject.

When this is fixed, you still need to fix the declaration for `CreateRenderer1()` as others pointed out - either forward-declare `struct IRenderingEngine;` before the function or just move it after the definition of the `struct`.

Comment: I have no plain objective-c files (except for main.m, which would have exploded earlier when I had the entire OpenGL implementation in GLView.mm). If all else fails I will try this suggestion.

Comment: @Dusda: You have to include/import `GLView.h` somewhere to use it? Either all source files including it are Objective-C++ or you write `GLView.h` so that plain Objective-C sources can use it too.

Comment: @Dusda: I'm telling you that you *shouldn't* import it in `GLView.h`. If you only include `GLView.h` in `GLView.mm` you shouldn't have problems after fixing the problem with `CreateRenderer1()` - but that error strongly suggests that you *are* including `GLView.h` in a `.m` file.

Comment: Okay, I removed the #import reference to IRenderingEngine.hpp from GLView.h, added **struct IRenderingEngine;** to GLView.h, and then added the **#import "IRenderingEngine.hpp"** to GLView.mm. It compiles now, albeit with a complaint about CreateRenderer1() (I'm assuming because I haven't written an implementation for it yet). I think that worked.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I was able to finish the rest of the app with no trouble. I'm probably going to pick up a C++ book now, so I can understand how forward declarations work, among other things. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 5):

You need to rename HelloArrowAppDelegate.m to a .mm file. It states in the book on page 20 (middle section with the paws bullet point). I missed that section and had the same problem. After changing the file to .mm the program worked.

Comment: this did the trick for me (also if you other files such as HelloArrowAppDelegate_Ipad.m you will need to rename those too)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. It turned out to be due to the fact that renaming HelloArrowAppDelegate.m to HelloArrowAppDelegate.mm in Xcode's Groups & Files did not actually rename the file! Once I used Finder to rename it the project compiled OK. Note Xcode may complain that the HelloArrowAppDelegate.m is missing when you open the project again, just right click it, delete it and then use "Add existing files" to add the HelloArrowAppDelegate.mm file back in.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem a cop-out but I had exactly the same problem when I updated to XCode 4.x

I got around it by downloading the source code from O'reilly's website and just loaded the project. Xcode appeared to recognise it as an old project and configured itself accordingly; no compilation issues, worked first time. It's not the same as typing it in yourself but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line is causing the error:

```
struct IRenderingEngine* CreateRenderer1();
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do there, but I think it should be removed entirely.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but the book specifically leaves it in the place I left it above, and moving it below the IRenderingEngine struct didn't change the compiler error reported. The idea presented in the book is that CreateRenderer1() will create an OpenGL ES 1.1 implementation, with another one added later called CreateRenderer2() that implements OpenGL ES 2.0 (for fallback purposes).

Comment: Well, it certainly has to go after the definition of the IRenderingEngine struct as fbrereto mentioned, but even then it's not really valid. Maybe it's supposed to be a function pointer? e.g. `struct IRenderingEngine (*CreateRenderer1)()`

Comment: I've tried commenting **struct IRenderingEngine* CreateRenderer1()** out entirely (I'm not actually using it yet anyway), and it hasn't had any effect.

Comment: Maybe this'll help? http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/631-how-to-get-c-and-objective-c-to-play-nicely-in-xcode/

Comment: I found that while googling around haven't tried it yet because the book does it differently. I'll give it a shot real quick though.

Comment: Well, I don't think I can be much more help at this point. I don't do any iphone dev, i just know enough about C++ to see what was wrong at that point. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
struct IRenderingEngine* CreateRenderer1();
```

Must come after the declaration of the `IRenderingEngine` class. (Also, if you intended to use the variable as a pointer to that structure type you should omit the parentheses in its declaration.)

For your other error I think you want to prepend the line with `struct`.

Comment: The other error might go away once the first problem is fixed?

Comment: I added **struct** to the second line that was breaking and it removed the compiler error. However, the book explicitly defines the line as "IRenderingEngine* m_renderingEngine;", and since I'm not well-versed in c++ I'm afraid to question the syntax :(.

Comment: Oh, and the **struct** change to the second error did not remove the first. It's still complaining about the struct IRenderingEngine in the .hpp file.